# How to find the position of a widget inside of a scrollview w.r.t scroll position/offset?

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollview

I have three sections inside of a `ScrollView` i.e. `Personal Info`, `Education` and `Experience`. I also have a custom header widget with the same names.

I am trying to implement `#id` like on web for scroll view controller and change header selcted.

I need to highlight the apporpriate header item as I scroll up/down the list and hit the section. The code so far is as follows:

```dart
import 'package:app/core/helpers/assets.dart';
import 'package:app/core/palettes/palettes.dart';
import 'package:app/core/utils/responsive_builder_utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import '../../../view_models/profile_education_model.dart';
import '../../../view_models/profile_experience_model.dart';

final List<ProfileExperienceModel> kExperiences = [
  ProfileExperienceModel(
    positionName: 'Registered Nurse',
    companyNameAndLocation: 'Royal Melbourne Hospital,  Parkville, Australia',
    startDate: DateTime.utc(2017, 3, 12),
    endDate: DateTime.utc(2019, 3, 12),
  ),
  ProfileExperienceModel(
    positionName: 'Registered Nurse',
    companyNameAndLocation: 'Royal Melbourne Hospital,  Parkville, Australia',
    startDate: DateTime.utc(2019, 4, 15),
    isCurrentlyWorking: true,
  ),
];

final List<ProfileEducationModel> kEducations = [
  ProfileEducationModel(
    degreeName: 'Master in Business Studies',
    universityNameAndLocation: 'Tribhuvan University, Nepal',
    startDate: DateTime.utc(2021, 06, 12),
    isCurrentlyStudying: true,
  ),
  ProfileEducationModel(
    degreeName: 'Bachelor in Information Management',
    universityNameAndLocation: 'Tribhuvan University, Nepal',
    startDate: DateTime.utc(2017, 01, 18),
    endDate: DateTime.utc(2021, 01, 12),
  ),
  ProfileEducationModel(
    degreeName: 'Intermediate degree',
    universityNameAndLocation: 'Higher Secondary Education Board (HSEB)',
    startDate: DateTime.utc(2014, 01, 18),
    endDate: DateTime.utc(2016, 01, 01),
  ),
  ProfileEducationModel(
    degreeName: 'School Leaving Certificate (SLC)',
    universityNameAndLocation: 'Govt. of Nepal',
    startDate: DateTime.utc(1998, 01, 18),
    endDate: DateTime.utc(2014, 01, 01),
  ),
];

class ProfilePersonalSummaryPageView extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfilePersonalSummaryPageView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const kVerticalSeparatorSmall = SizedBox(height: 8);
    const kVerticalSeparator = SizedBox(height: 12);
    const kVerticalSeparatorLarge = SizedBox(height: 16);
    const kVerticalSeparatorVeryLarge = SizedBox(height: 24);

    return Container(
      color: const Color(0xFFF6FAFF),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: kScaffoldPadding(context: context).copyWith(
            top: 20,
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const Text(
                  'Lorem ipsum'
                  ),
              kVerticalSeparatorLarge,
              personalDetailWidget(
                  context: context,
                  svgAsset: SvgAssets.phoneIcon,
                  text: '123456789'),
              kVerticalSeparatorSmall,
              personalDetailWidget(
                  context: context,
                  svgAsset: SvgAssets.emailIcon,
                  text: 'some@email.com'),
              kVerticalSeparatorSmall,
              personalDetailWidget(
                  context: context,
                  svgAsset: SvgAssets.profileRegistrationIdIcon,
                  text: '1234'),
              kVerticalSeparatorVeryLarge,

              /// region - Experience Block
              Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  /// Experience Header
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Experience',
                        style:
                            Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium?.copyWith(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                ),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                            minimumSize: Size.zero,
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            'Add',
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .titleSmall
                                ?.copyWith(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                ),
                          )),
                    ],
                  ),

                  kVerticalSeparatorLarge,

                  /// Experiences
                  ListView.separated(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final experience = kExperiences[index];
                        String workingPeriod =
                            '${DateFormat.yMMM().format(experience.startDate)} - ';

                        if (experience.isCurrentlyWorking &&
                            experience.endDate == null) {
                          workingPeriod = '$workingPeriod Present';
                        } else {
                          workingPeriod =
                              '$workingPeriod ${DateFormat.yMMM().format(experience.endDate!)}';
                        }

                        return Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 12, vertical: 8),
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Flexible(
                                        child: Text(
                                      experience.positionName,
                                      maxLines: 1,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: Theme.of(context)
                                          .textTheme
                                          .titleSmall
                                          ?.copyWith(
                                              color: Theme.of(context)
                                                  .primaryColor),
                                    )),
                                    const SizedBox(width: 12),
                                    IconButton(
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      icon: const Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
                                      iconSize: 24,
                                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                      visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
                                        horizontal:
                                            VisualDensity.minimumDensity,
                                        vertical: VisualDensity.minimumDensity,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height: 4),
                                Text(experience.companyNameAndLocation,
                                    maxLines: 2,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: Theme.of(context)
                                        .textTheme
                                        .bodyMedium
                                        ?.copyWith(
                                          color: const Color(0xFF545A60),
                                        )),
                                const SizedBox(height: 8),
                                Text(workingPeriod,
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: Theme.of(context)
                                        .textTheme
                                        .bodyMedium
                                        ?.copyWith(
                                          color: AppPalette.kTextColorLight,
                                        )),
                              ]),
                        );
                      },
                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => kVerticalSeparator,
                      itemCount: kExperiences.length)
                ],
              ),

              /// endregion - Experience Block
              kVerticalSeparatorVeryLarge,

              /// region - Education Block
              Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  /// Education Header
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Education',
                        style:
                            Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium?.copyWith(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                ),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                            minimumSize: Size.zero,
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            'Add',
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .titleSmall
                                ?.copyWith(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                ),
                          )),
                    ],
                  ),

                  kVerticalSeparatorLarge,

                  /// Educations
                  ListView.separated(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final education = kEducations[index];
                        String studyPeriod =
                            '${DateFormat.y().format(education.startDate)} - ';

                        if (education.isCurrentlyStudying &&
                            education.endDate == null) {
                          studyPeriod = '$studyPeriod Present';
                        } else {
                          studyPeriod =
                              '$studyPeriod ${DateFormat.y().format(education.endDate!)}';
                        }

                        return Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 12, vertical: 8),
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Flexible(
                                        child: Text(
                                      education.degreeName,
                                      maxLines: 1,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: Theme.of(context)
                                          .textTheme
                                          .titleSmall
                                          ?.copyWith(
                                              color: Theme.of(context)
                                                  .primaryColor),
                                    )),
                                    const SizedBox(width: 12),
                                    IconButton(
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      icon: const Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
                                      iconSize: 24,
                                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                      visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
                                        horizontal:
                                            VisualDensity.minimumDensity,
                                        vertical: VisualDensity.minimumDensity,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                // const SizedBox(height: 4),
                                Text(education.universityNameAndLocation,
                                    maxLines: 2,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: Theme.of(context)
                                        .textTheme
                                        .bodyMedium
                                        ?.copyWith(
                                          color: const Color(0xFF545A60),
                                        )),
                                const SizedBox(height: 8),
                                Text(studyPeriod,
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: Theme.of(context)
                                        .textTheme
                                        .bodyMedium
                                        ?.copyWith(
                                          color: AppPalette.kTextColorLight,
                                        )),
                              ]),
                        );
                      },
                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => kVerticalSeparator,
                      itemCount: kEducations.length)
                ],
              ),

              /// endregion - Experience Block
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget personalDetailWidget(
    {required BuildContext context,
    required String svgAsset,
    required String text}) {
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      SvgPicture.asset(
        svgAsset,
        width: 14,
        height: 14,
      ),
      const SizedBox(width: 12),
      Text(text),
    ],
  );
}
```

File: profile.dart

```dart
import 'package:app/core/themes/theme.dart';
import 'package:app/core/widgets/atoms/shimmer/app_shimmer.dart';
import 'package:app/features/home/presentation/widgets/atoms/mobile/profile/personal_summary.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../../../../../../core/helpers/assets.dart';
import '../../../../../../../core/widgets/atoms/tab.dart';

class HomeMobilePortraitViewProfileWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeMobilePortraitViewProfileWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeMobilePortraitViewProfileWidget> createState() =>
      _HomeMobilePortraitViewProfileWidgetState();
}

class _HomeMobilePortraitViewProfileWidgetState
    extends State<HomeMobilePortraitViewProfileWidget> {
  final _kHeaderHeight = 300.0;
  final _kProfileImageSize = 146.0;
  final _kProfileImageBorder = 8.0;

  ValueNotifier<int> currentSelectedTab = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
  PageController? pageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController?.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final kBackgroundImageHeight = _kHeaderHeight / 2.0;

    List<AppDefaultTab> tabs = [
      AppDefaultTab(
          index: 0,
          title: 'Personal Summary',
          currentSelectedTab: currentSelectedTab),
      AppDefaultTab(
          index: 1,
          title: 'Experience',
          currentSelectedTab: currentSelectedTab),
      AppDefaultTab(
          index: 2, title: 'Education', currentSelectedTab: currentSelectedTab),
    ];

    return Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            /// region - Profile & Bg Image, and name and address
            SizedBox(
              height: _kHeaderHeight,
              child: Stack(children: [
                /// background image
                Container(
                  height: kBackgroundImageHeight,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl:
                        'https://picsum.photos/2400/1800?v=${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}',
                    height: kBackgroundImageHeight,
                    imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                      height: kBackgroundImageHeight,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      child: Image(
                          image: imageProvider,
                          height: kBackgroundImageHeight,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    ),
                    placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
                      height: kBackgroundImageHeight,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      child: AppShimmer(
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(
                      height: kBackgroundImageHeight,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                /// Name and address
                Positioned.fill(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      height: _kHeaderHeight / 2,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      color: const Color(0xFFF6FAFF),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          const Spacer(flex: 3),
                          Text(
                            'Some Name',
                            maxLines: 1,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .titleMedium
                                ?.copyWith(fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'New York, ',
                            maxLines: 1,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .bodyMedium
                                ?.copyWith(
                                  fontFamily: ThemeManager.kFontFamily,
                                  fontSize: 13,
                                  color: const Color(0xFFA1A1A1),
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                ),
                          ),
                          const Spacer(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                /// Profile photo
                Positioned.fill(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                      imageUrl:
                          'https://picsum.photos/1600/900?v=${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}',
                      width: _kProfileImageSize,
                      height: _kProfileImageSize,
                      imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                        width: _kProfileImageSize,
                        height: _kProfileImageSize,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(_kProfileImageBorder),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                              (_kProfileImageSize - _kProfileImageBorder) / 2),
                          child: Image(
                              image: imageProvider,
                              width:
                                  (_kProfileImageSize - _kProfileImageBorder),
                              height:
                                  (_kProfileImageSize - _kProfileImageBorder),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover),
                        ),
                      ),
                      placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
                        width: _kProfileImageSize,
                        height: _kProfileImageSize,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(_kProfileImageBorder),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                              (_kProfileImageSize - _kProfileImageBorder) / 2),
                          child: AppShimmer(
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(
                        width: _kProfileImageSize,
                        height: _kProfileImageSize,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(_kProfileImageBorder),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                              (_kProfileImageSize - _kProfileImageBorder) / 2),
                          child: Image.asset(ImageAssets.avatarPlaceholder,
                              cacheHeight:
                                  (_kProfileImageSize - _kProfileImageBorder)
                                      .toInt(),
                              cacheWidth:
                                  (_kProfileImageSize - _kProfileImageBorder)
                                      .toInt(),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            ),

            /// endregion - Profile & Bg Image, and name and address

            /// region -
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 60,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemBuilder: (listViewBuilderContext, index) =>
                            GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  currentSelectedTab.value = index;
                                  // pageController?.jumpToPage(index);
                                },
                                child: tabs[index]),
                        itemCount: tabs.length),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            const Expanded(
              child: ProfilePersonalSummaryPageView(),
            ),

            /// endregion -
            ///
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

I am using ValueNotifier to track the currently selected tab.

Comment: do you want to navigate to a specific index in listView?

Comment: yes...but not in a list view in a scroll view. please share your approach on ListView. I can convert the scroll view to a default ListView()